# При выдачи текстовых файлов в Django получаю иероглифы

Tags: django

При выдаче статических файлов в Django браузер открывает их в какой-то не понятной кодировке, но если открыть файл на компьютер и сохранить его, то кодировка возвращается в UTF-8. Смена браузера не помогает)

setting.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/scripts_controller/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файлы в какой кодировке? Чем именно отдаётся статика?

Comment: Что за файлы? При чем тут django, раз они static?

Comment: файл в Utf8,  при попытке получить файл через сервер django localhost:8080\media\filename

Comment: ИМХО у автора каша в голове... Кодировку определяет в основном не django, а template к примеру, или содержимое файла... Нужно больше информации.

Comment: Нажмите F12 в хроме и посмотрите source для текущей страницы. Скриншот сюда.

Comment: проблема в том что переходя по ссылке к файлу, браузер открывает в непонятной кодировке, можно ли как-то настроить кодировку для файлов медия в django?

Comment: нажимаю F12 и там те же иероглифы, если сохраняю то текст отлично отображается

Comment: Скриншот нужен. Если иероглифы и там в заголовках консоли разработчика, то проблема скорее в вашей системе, а не в django

Comment: Что-то тут у всех каша в голове, для статических файлов (особенно текстовых) кодировку определять некому, надо её каким-то способом пихать вручную в заголовок Content-Type. Но как это делать в dev-сервере я не в курсе

Comment: @andreymal Content-Type берется из mimetypes (наводка)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич MIME-тип для .txt файлов - text/plain. Как джанга должна определить кодировку, владея этой информацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, статика у вас отдаётся devserver'ом. По умолчанию для этого используется представление `django.views.static.serve`, которое не устанавливает кодировку для http-ответа. А значит в соответствии со [стандартом HTTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) это будет ISO-8859-1. Естественно, ваш браузер отобразит крякозяблы при попытке вывести текст не в той кодировке.

Comment: Так тоже можно отдавать, но всё ж в dev-сервере статика и медиа раздаются автоматически без явного прописывания в urls.py (при DEBUG=True)

Comment: да у меня есть **if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)**, и получается это никак нельзя исправить?

Comment: @andreymal и правда. Исправил.

Comment: можно только сделать обработку данного запроса самостоятельно, с выдачей кодировки и файла?

Comment: @Артур а зачем Вам это на static.serve? Оно работает только во время DEBUG, что например в production не имеет никакого смысла. Переделать можно всё, вопрос в том надо ли тратить на это время...